# How to work with Azure Active Directory Schema Extensions in Multi-Tenant Scenario

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use an Azure AD schema extension to extend one property, I have successfully created a schema extension with id "`myverifiedaaddomain_extensionid`".

Schema Extension  :

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions/$entity",
    "id": "myverifiedaaddomain_extensionid",
    "description": "myverifiedaaddomain_extensionid",
    "targetTypes": [
        "User"
    ],
    "status": "InDevelopment",
    "owner": "owner",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "isExtended",
            "type": "Boolean"
        }
    ]
}
```

***NOTE: It is working perfectly fine in single tenant scenario.***

---

**Multi-tenant scenario :**

Scenario -

1. I have a host tenant T1
2. Registered multi-tenant AAD AAP A1 (in T1
   with all required permissions)
3. I want to on-board tenant T2
4. Register schema extension on T2 after successful on-boarding

**When I on-board T2, all schema extensions from T1 where owner is A1 get's imported in T2's directory without any notification or prompt.**

So currently It is working in multi-tenant scenario as well but I am not sure about getting all schema extensions exported to partner tenant(T2), **is it expected behaviour or a bug?** 
There is no clear documentation available here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/schemaextension?view=graph-rest-1.0

Apart from this there is **no clear documentation on permissions as well**, for example :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#permissions
They mentioned that, in order to read/update extended data, you need all permissions mentioned on that resource permission page. For `User` resource we will need to have all permissions mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions

This is not working, **I am not able to read extended data via other AAD apps(A2, A3 etc.)** which has all permissions mentioned in above page(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for some of the challenges you are coming across here.  Just to double check - have you used Azure AD Directory Schema extensions in the past?  I'm asking because it seems like you have some preconceptions about how extensions work - and they behave a little differently in Microsoft Graph.

In terms of documentation - it is documented in the section about schema extension lifecycle in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#schema-extensions.  Maybe we can do a better job of providing a full on scenario.  But here's the relevant bit when setting the schema definition state to `Available`:

- The schema extension is available for use by **all apps in any tenant**.
- After the owner app sets the extension to Available, **any app can
  simply add custom data to instances of those resource types specified
  in the extension (as long as the app has permissions to that
  resource)**. The app can assign custom data when creating a new
  instance or updating an existing instance.
- Only the owner app can
  update the extension definition with additive changes. No app can
  delete the extension definition in this state.
- The owner app can
  move the schema extension from Available to the Deprecated state.

In terms of the permissions not working, what permissions were granted to the multi-tenant application, or the other apps A2 and A3?  What response are you seeing (can you provide the request as well please)?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi @Dan, Thanks for the answer. 
In multi-tenant scenario, all schema extensions registered/associated with AAD App gets exported to the tenant which is being on-boarded. There is no information on consent page about it. 

Regarding the permissions, I was trying access extended property from other APP while my extension was in Development phase. That is sorted now.

Comment: By the way there is one more issue which I am facing : $filter is available on "/groups/{groupId}/members" resource. But in the document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#filtering-on-schema-extension-properties-not-supported-on-all-entity-types they did not mentioned that filtering is not available on /groups/{groupId}/members. Any thoughts on this?